# Is there a way to Lock user access on Ubuntu (without disabling the screen)?

Tags: unity, lubuntu, lock-screen

Is there a way to Lock a Ubuntu Desktop without blanking out the screen?

My objective is to allow everyone to view whats happening on Ubuntu Desktops, but not give anyone access to them without entering the password. The desktops are all within the workplace.

I know the simple Lock Screen will simply Lock the whole desktop screen and blank it out, But I'm looking for a similar feature that Does Not blank out the screen, but show it openly. We have some financial/transactional and News WE WANT to display (But not modify) except by the financial Admins.

I have not seen this feature in any operating system. Is there a addon/plugin out there that might Lock the screen from Keyboard/Mouse without blanking the desktop screen?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: wouldn't it be enough than to lock all mouse and keaboard inputs? (well than you would have to unlock over ssh for example ;) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [xtrlock](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=xtrlock&searchon=names)

```
$ sudo apt install xtrlock
```

To unlock, type the password on the screen.

### Automatic Lockscreen Timeout script

I wrote a quick lockscreen timeout script that will auto start the lock when the computer is idle.  It works like a screen saver.

To enable it, run **startup app** from the Ubuntu Dash Search to add it to your autostart applications.

The script needs `xprintidle` to run.

```
$ sudo apt install xprintidle`
```

**The Script**

lockscreen.sh:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# The lock timoeout defaults to 15 minutes.
# Enter an argument on the commanline to for a different timeout.
# xptintidle needs to be installed for the script to work

if [[ ! $(type xprintidle 2>/dev/null) ]]; then
    notify-send "xprintidle not installed... lockscreen not enabled."
    exit
fi
idle=15
[[ "$1" ]] && idle=$1
while :; do
    if (($(xprintidle) > idle * 60000)); then
        [[ $(ps h -C xtrlock) ]] || xtrlock
    fi
    sleep 10
done
```

Comment: Thanks for acknowledging the answer.  I added a script and instructions to auto start the lock when the screen is idle.  This can be useful for the times when the operator is away and forgets to manually set the lock.

Comment: Thanks James. I added the **xtrlock** to the Ubuntu panel as a shortcut to make life easy for everyone.. I bet they will like the auto lock feature as well.. Thanks again, this was really helpful.